# Android Layout does not display controls

Tags: android

I am writing my first android app after reading a tutorial. I am excited and thought its easy. However, after adding a simple edit text and a hello world message, i run and was expecting to see something yet nothing showed up. Neither the textbox nor the default hello world. Pls where do go wrong ? Below is my layout (i.e activity_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:textColor="#FF00FF00"/>

      <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:textColor="#FF0000FF"
             android:id="@+id/et_Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code is the default/code generated one. I was expecting to see atleast the message for a start yet didn't  show any control. Just a screen with a phone dialers on the rigth hand.

```
package com.example.mytest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where in the Java code you are actually using this layout?

Comment: is your xml file name `mainactitivy.xml` or `activity_main.xml`

Comment: No its activity_main. SOrry for the mistake

Comment: hey i tried it out, it works for me [image-dump](https://dyp.im/delete/y65ivjX5DbJuuWjD)

Comment: I checked thoroughly again . I am not surprise it works. @Sagar do u think may be i have hardware prob ? or my simulator ? when i run  its  displaying time on the screen just like a phone, yet the message is not there and the edittext is missing as well.

Comment: where do you get `edittext is missing as well.` message ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using RelativeLayout, you need to tell Android how each control is relative to each other. Change the layout as follow:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"/>

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:textColor="#FF0000FF"
         android:id="@+id/et_Text" />
```

This will tell the system to place the EditText below the TextView.